# VBA Wrap IFERROR Modification

Tags: vba, excel

I am very rusty with VBA and as such I expect this will be an easy modification for those who are more well versed with VBA. I want to modify the below formula to allow me to have my IFERROR function return either 0 , "" , or n/a in the event of an error. Currently the code I found online is perfect but does not return n/a. If someone knows how to quickly add a block of code that allows the third option to cycle through would appreciate it. The code is from www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

```
Sub WrapIfError_v2()

'PURPOSE: Add an IFERROR() Function around all the selected cells' formulas. _
          Also handles if IFERROR is already wrapped around formula.
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim AlreadyIFERROR As Boolean
Dim RemoveIFERROR As Boolean
Dim TestEnd1 As String
Dim TestEnd2 As String
Dim TestEnd3 As String
Dim TestStart As String
Dim MyFormula As String
Dim x As String

'Determine if a single cell or range is selected
  If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Set rng = Selection
    If Not rng.HasFormula Then GoTo NoFormulas
  Else
    'Get Range of Cells that Only Contain Formulas
      On Error GoTo NoFormulas
        Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
      On Error GoTo 0
  End If

'Get formula from First cell in Selected Range
  MyFormula = rng(1, 1).Formula

'Create Test Strings To Determine if IFERROR formula has already been added
  TestEnd1 = Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
  TestEnd2 = ",0)"
  TestStart = Left(MyFormula, 9)

'Determine How we want to modify formula
  If Right(MyFormula, 3) = TestEnd1 And TestStart = "=IFERROR(" Then
    Beg_String = ""
    End_String = "0)" '=IFERROR([formula],0)
    AlreadyIFERROR = True
  ElseIf Right(MyFormula, 3) = ",0)" And TestStart = "=IFERROR(" Then
    RemoveIFERROR = True
  Else
    Beg_String = "=IFERROR("
    End_String = "," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")" '=IFERROR([formula],"")
    AlreadyIFERROR = False
  End If

'Loop Through Each Cell in Range and modify formula
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    x = cell.Formula

    If RemoveIFERROR = True Then
      cell = "=" & Mid(x, 10, Len(x) - 12)
    ElseIf AlreadyIFERROR = False Then
      cell = Beg_String & Right(x, Len(x) - 1) & End_String
    Else
      cell = Left(x, Len(x) - 3) & End_String
    End If

  Next cell

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NoFormulas:
  MsgBox "There were no formulas found in your selection!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you're after - N/A ***is*** an error.

Comment: N/A as in the string "N/A", not the error...

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in changing the value of End_String in the following code block:

```
'Determine How we want to modify formula
  If Right(MyFormula, 3) = TestEnd1 And TestStart = "=IFERROR(" Then
    Beg_String = ""
    End_String = "0)" '=IFERROR([formula],0)
    AlreadyIFERROR = True
  ElseIf Right(MyFormula, 3) = ",0)" And TestStart = "=IFERROR(" Then
    RemoveIFERROR = True
  Else
    Beg_String = "=IFERROR("
    End_String = "," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")" '=IFERROR([formula],"")
    AlreadyIFERROR = False
  End If
```

For example, instead the

```
& Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

you could substitute:

```
& "NA())"
```

Is that close to what you were looking for?